# Is it possible to do a "zoom inset" using seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, insets

[This example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axes_demo.html) from matplotlib shows how to do an inset. However I am working with seaborn, specifically the kdeplot.

```
sns.kdeplot(y, label='default bw')
sns.kdeplot(y, bw=0.5, label="bw: 0.2", alpha=0.6)
sns.kdeplot(y, linestyle="--", bw=2, label="bw: 2", alpha=0.6)
sns.kdeplot(y, linestyle=":", bw=5, label="bw: 5", alpha=0.6)
```

It so happens that I have a lot of empty space on the right side of the graph and I would like to put a zoomed in inset there to clarify the lower x range. (If need be I could move the legend out as well, but that's besides the point)

[image]

Is it possible to do that with seaborn alone or do I have to forego the convenience of seaborn and convert the plots to matplotlib?

Comment: Yes, you can do exactly what is shown in the link you have posted which does of course _use_ matplotlib but can interact with the plots made in seaborn

Comment: There is also a "zoomed_inset" capability with matplotlib that you can also use with seaborn. Example with matplotlib - https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/inset_locator_demo2.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

seaborn is just a wrapper around matplotlib, you do not have to chose one or the other. In your case, [you can instruct `sns.distplot()` to use whathever Axes object you want using the `ax=` parameter](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)

Therefore:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.distplot(d, ax=ax)

ax2 = plt.axes([0.2, 0.6, .2, .2], facecolor='y')
sns.distplot(d, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('zoom')
ax2.set_xlim([0.9,1.])
```

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what `plt` is? I assume that's `matplotlib.pyplot`?