# How to zoom in out seaborn boxplot using plt.figure and add_subplot?

Tags: python, plot, zooming, seaborn, boxplot

There is lot of examples of zooming in on plots using fig, ax = plt.subplots().

However I have a code where i am using fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,11)) and thus have fig.add_subplot(311) and fig.add_subplot(312) and fig.add_subplot(313).

How can i zoom in on an area in one of these specific subplots if i want to?

Each subplot is a sns.boxplot in my case.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,11))

fig.add_subplot(312) #This is the second subplot of the three plots 

bp2 = sns.boxplot(y='SR [-]', x='Spin Setup', 
             data=df, 
             palette="colorblind",
             hue='Rubber', 
             width=0.5,
             fliersize=3)
```

See picture of my second plot amongst the three. I want to zoom in on the boxplots at xtick-value of 3 and 6.

[image: the three plots]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED with this code

```
fig.add_subplot(312)

yval2='SR [-]'

bp2 = sns.boxplot(y=yval2, x=xval, 
                 data=df, 
                 palette="colorblind",
                 hue='Rubber', 
                 width=0.5,
                 fliersize=3)

bp2.set_ylabel(yval2,fontsize=11.5)
bp2.set_xlabel(xval,fontsize=11.5)
bp2.legend()

ax2 = plt.axes([0.18, 0.44, .16, .08], facecolor='#eafff5') #Venstre boxplot
z2 = sns.boxplot(y=yval2, x=xval, data=df.loc[(df[xval]== -30)], palette="colorblind", hue='Rubber', width=0.5, fliersize=3, ax=ax2)
z2.set_title('zoom',fontsize=8,fontweight='semibold', y=1.02)
z2.set_xticks([])
z2.set(xlabel=None)
z2.set(ylabel=None)
z2.legend_.remove()
#
ax3 = plt.axes([0.46, 0.38, .16, .08], facecolor='#eafff5') #Middle boxplot
z3 = sns.boxplot(y=yval2, x=xval, data=df.loc[(df[xval]== 0)], palette="colorblind", hue='Rubber', width=0.5, fliersize=3, ax=ax3)
z3.set_title('zoom',fontsize=8,fontweight='semibold', y=1.02)
z3.set_xticks([])
z3.set(xlabel=None)
z3.set(ylabel=None)
z3.legend_.remove()
#z.set_ylim(-0.65,-0.5)

ax4 = plt.axes([0.76, 0.38+0.10, .16, .08], facecolor='#eafff5') #Højre boxplot
z4 = sns.boxplot(y=yval2, x=xval, data=df.loc[(df[xval]== 30)], palette="colorblind", hue='Rubber', width=0.5, fliersize=3, ax=ax4)
z4.set_title('zoom',fontsize=8,fontweight='semibold', y=1.02)
z4.set_xticks([])
z4.set(xlabel=None)
z4.set(ylabel=None)
z4.legend_.remove()
```

Output is this [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in showing the boxes for `spin setup == 0` in the second plot, you could exclude them using `df.loc[df['Spin Setup'] != 0`]:

```
bp2 = sns.boxplot(y='SR [-]', x='Spin Setup', 
             data=df.loc[df['Spin Setup'] != 0`], 
             palette="colorblind",
             hue='Rubber', 
             width=0.5,
             fliersize=3)
```

Another solution is to set the y- and x-axis manually using `bp2.set_xlim(2.5, 6.5)` and `bp2.set_ylim(-1, 0)`

Comment: I do want to show the boxes for spin setup == 0. Thus, i was looking for something like the solutions in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160719/is-it-possible-to-do-a-zoom-inset-using-seaborn?rq=1

Comment: @MatiMalik Ah ok, I see. Does the answer to that question solve your problem? Then I will vote to close this as a duplicate. If not, could you edit your question to indicate how it is different from the one you just linked?